# Inequality of an expression greater than 0

Tags: inequality

[Wolfram](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%28x%2B1%29%5E%28x%2B1%29+%2B+2%5E%28x%2B1%29+x%5Ex>%3D0%3B+x>0) says the following is true for all $x>0$:

$$-(x+1)^{(x+1) }+ 2^{(x+1)} x^x\geq0$$

How to prove this algebraically?

Comment: Are you interested in all real $x>0$, or just integers? If all real, have you tried differentiation? If only integers, have you tried the binomial theorem?

Comment: @Arthur For integer case, when I use binomial theorem I end up getting $(x+1)^{(x+1) }<=2^{(x+1)} x^{(x+1)}$, which doesn't seem to be tight! Any help on this?

Answer (score 2):

Since $x >0$, instead of considering function $$f(x)= 2^{(x+1)} x^x-(x+1)^{(x+1) }$$ consider instead
$$g(x)=\log\left(2^{(x+1)} x^x\right) -\log\left((x+1)^{(x+1) } \right)$$ $$g(x)=(x+1)\log(2)+x \log(x)-(x+1)\log(x+1)$$
Now, the derivatives
$$g'(x)=\log (x)-\log (x+1)+\log (2)\qquad \text{and} \qquad g''(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+x}\qquad > 0 \qquad \forall x >0$$
The first derivative cancels at $x=1$. For this value $g(1)=0$ and by the second serivative test, this is a minimum. So, no root for $g(x)=0$ which is a decreasing function for $ 0 < x <1$, goes through a minimum and increases again (for ever).

Comment: Very neat, as usual with your solutions...

Comment: @JeanMarie. Thank you. I really appreciate, be sure. Cheers :-)

Comment: Great. I was so fixated upon when $x$ were integers that this method went over my head. Do you know if we can use Binomial theorem when $x$ are integers to show the same inequality? I end up getting $(x+1)^{(x+1) }<=2^{(x+1)} x^{(x+1)}$, which doesn't seem to be tight!